# Preventing shapefile lines becoming rasterized when exported as PDF by ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pdf, rasterization

In ArcGIS for Desktop some Line feature shapefile becomes raster when exported as pdf.

In exported PDF the line features layer is not present as it becomes raster.

The line features are mixed with satellite image and not exported as different layer in PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The software behaviour that you are observing is documented under [Exporting your map: Troubleshooting map export: Rasterization](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sm00000004000000):

> Layer transparency and BMP-based picture symbols can cause maps to
>   become rasterized when output. The effect of rasterization is that all
>   layers below the data layer containing transparency or BMP picture
>   symbols will be converted to a flat raster image in the export or
>   print spool file. Rasterization can also occur to any layer contained
>   in the same group layer as a transparent layer. To avoid
>   rasterization, BMP picture symbols should be replaced with vector-only
>   EMF pictures or with font based character marker symbols. Eliminating
>   unnecessary use of layer transparency can also help alleviate unwanted
>   layer rasterization.

There is additional advice on detecting/preventing rasterization offered on that page.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Advanced` tab of the PDF export, check the box `Export Geometries`.  Then select `Export Layers Only` or `Export Layers and Feature Attributes` depending on whether you just want the features or also the data associated with them.  See the documentation [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00sm00000007000000).

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you want to hear, I’m sure, and you probably have no say in the matter, anyway, but if you want transparency on vectors in the output, use QGIS. Just don’t set any layer as a whole to a transparency. You need to go one step deeper to where fill and line colors can be manipulated. Transparency set here will output as vectors, with transparency.